# Proof that eigenvalues of the Coulomb hamiltonian are not nonnegative

Tags: integration, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Let's consider the Coulomb Hamiltonian

$$
-\Delta - \frac{1}{|x|}$$

in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

It is known that eigenvalues of the Coulomb Hamiltonian are negative.

I know it has negative eigenvalues, but I can't prove it hasn't nonnegative eigenvalues.

That is, I want to prove the following.

If smooth function $u$ satisfies the following

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3
} |u(x)|^2 dx + \int_{\mathbb{R}^3
} |\nabla u(x)|^2 dx ＜ \infty$$ and

$$-\Delta u - \frac{u}{|x|} = \lambda u$$ for some $\lambda \geq 0$, then $u=0$.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that supposed to read $$H_{C} = \color{red}{-} \Delta \color{red}{-} \frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert}$$ i.e the dashes are actually minus signs?

Comment: @mattos Yes, it is.

Comment: States with $\lambda \geq 0$ exist: They are $\tt scattering\ states$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V(x) = -\frac{1}{|x|}$ be the potential and $H = -\Delta + V$. We know that $H$ is a self-adjoint operator on $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Let $U(t)\psi(x) = e^{-\frac{3t}{2}}\psi(e^{-t}x)$. $U$ is a strongly continuous unitary group (dilation).

Now let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $H$. Since $H$ is self-adjoint and $U$  a unitary group, we have $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and
we observe that $\langle \psi, [U(t),H] \psi \rangle = \langle U(-t)\psi, H \psi \rangle + \langle H\psi, U(t)\psi \rangle = \langle U(-t)\psi, \lambda \psi \rangle + \langle \lambda\psi, U(t)\psi \rangle= 0$

Observe that the potential $V$ satisfies $U(-t)VU(t) = e^{-t}V$. So, $ 0 = \lim_{t \to 0} \langle \psi, \frac{1}{t}[U(t),H] \psi \rangle = \lim_{t \to 0} \langle U(-t)\psi, \frac{1}{t}(H - U(-t)HU(t)) \psi \rangle = \lim_{t \to 0} \langle \psi, \frac{1-e^{-2t}}{t} (-\Delta \psi)\rangle + \langle \psi, \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t} V\psi \rangle = \langle \psi, (-2\Delta + V) \psi \rangle = \langle \psi, -\Delta \psi + H\psi \rangle = \langle \psi, -\Delta \psi + \lambda\psi \rangle$

The calculation shows that, if $||\psi|| = 1$:

$-\lambda = \langle \psi, -\Delta \psi \rangle > 0$. So, the point spectrum is contained in $(-\infty, 0 )$.

Comment: @ psl2Z Thank you very much.

Comment: There are potentials which have [discrete eigenvalues of positive energy](http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/5.pdf). "there is an
ancient, explicit example due to von Neumann and Wigner".

Comment: @KeithMcClary Why downvote??? I proved for the potential $-\frac{1}{|x|}$ that the point spectrum is in $(-\infty, 0)$. There are no positive discrete eigenvalues, because the essential spectrum is $[0,\infty)$. If the potential $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}V = a \geq 0$ for example and is in $L^2+L^{\infty}$ then $\sigma_{ess} = [a,\infty)$ and maybe there are some discrete positive eigenvalues. But the question was about this specific potential $-\frac{1}{|x|}!$

Comment: Sorry, where does your argument depend on $V$ being Coulomb (and not the von Neumann and Wigner potential).

Comment: See: http://math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/R62.pdf#page=15 BTW, the part at the bottom of p.16 is amusing.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Well, if you look carefully you see that I used $U(-t)VU(t)=e^{-t}V$. That is not true for arbitrary potentials. I guess that the von Neumann and Wigner potential does not have this property...

Comment: Now I see. I can't change the vote unless you make an edit.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, there's a theorem that bound states with potentials that go to zero at infinity necessarily have negative total energy, otherwise the wave function is not normalizable. This implies eigenvalues of the energy will be non-positive. The remaining question is whether the ground state has 0 energy. Waves in a bounded region of space give rise to interference which tends to limit solutions to the associated wave equation, so bound states imply discrete Eigenvalues.

Now a Coulomb potential has scattering states, i.e. unbounded: [Coulomb Scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_scattering_state#:%7E:text=A%20Coulomb%20scattering%20state%20in,a%20finite%20region%20of%20space.). These have a continuous spectrum of positive eigenvalues.

Comment: @ThrlocTheRed Thank you very much.